# How to set age restriction using the new PHP lib?

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

My old method to set age restriction is like

```
$userID = $facebook->require_login($required_permissions = 'email, publish_stream,offline_access');
$info = array('age' => '18+');
$success = $facebook->api_client->admin_setRestrictionInfo($info);
```

while the old method to be deprecated soon, I have to rewrite the code. I tried all means, then find I should call the api method this way,

```
$accessToken=$facebook->getAccessToken();
echo "<BR>access_token is: ".$accessToken;
$result = $facebook->api(array(
      'method' => 'admin.setRestrictionInfo',
      'restriction_str' => json_encode(array('age' => '18+')),
      "access_token" => $accessToken,
));
```

However, it always throw the following error

```
access_token is: 112819402105453|9761b1a933b0277ff56453a6.1-1670893505|zJEVp2JXbHzRVSVXmJUgV-Fz13o
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: 15: This method must be called with an app access_token. thrown in /usr/local/chroot/carrotbid/home/php/facebook_api/base_facebook.php on line 708
```

Any solution? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this for a while and finally figured it out so I thought I'd throw the answer out there for you.

That `getAccessToken` thing is whack. Apparently that's just what token is being used by the SDK and not necessarily your app's token.

```
$access_token = $app_id . "|" . $app_secret;

$facebook->api(array(
    "access_token"=>$access_token,
     "method"=>"admin.setRestrictionInfo",
     "restriction_str"=>"{'location':'CA'}"
));
```

Obviously set the `$app_id` and `$app_secret` to yours. The structure for an app's access token is `[app id]|[app secret]`.

The structure for the URL call is:

```
https://api.facebook.com/method/admin.setRestrictionInfo?access_token=[APP_ID]|[APP_SECRET]&format=json&restriction_str={%22type%22:%22alcohol%22}
```

Hope this helps!!!